# Non-archimedean matrix fields

Tags: matrices, field-theory, ordered-fields

Are there any examples of sets $A\subseteq{\Bbb C}^{n\times n}$ for which you can find operations so that $(A,+,\,\cdot\ ,<)$ is a non-archimedean ordered field? I feel like the answer is probably no, because to get an ordered field out the structure would have to be very similar to ${\Bbb R}$, but then again matrix groups seem to have a lot of degrees of freedom, so I'm not so sure. (If the answer is no, what about for $A\subseteq{\Bbb C}^{\omega\times\omega}$ or even larger bases?)

Comment: What do you mean "find operations"?  So long as two sets have the same cardinality you can just fix an arbitrary bijection between then and define the operations that way...

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Fair enough. I was considering restricting $+$ and $\cdot$ to be the standard ones on matrices, but that may be too restrictive to make it a field, and there is no natural $<$ operation that I know of on matrices. What is the smallest example of a non-archimedean ordered field? (I don't think there are any finite ordered fields.)

Comment: Restricting just to the case of scalars: You cannot order a ring containing an imaginary quadratic number, or one with positive characteristic, in a way that is compatible with the ring structure. However, $\bf C$ and ${\bf C}_p$ for any prime $p$ are abstractly isomorphic, and the first is archimedean whereas the latter is non-archimedean as valued fields. It's not clear to me how matrices make the situation more interesting (only more difficult in how exactly to characterize when a matrix subring is closed under multiplicative inverses) than that of mere scalars.

Comment: @anon Some questions: what are ${\bf C}_p$ and "abstractly isomorphic"? The reason I am considering matrices is because for scalars, I am reasonably certain the answer is "no", since as I mentioned, the field would need to be characteristic 0, so it would need to be a field between ${\Bbb Q}$ and ${\Bbb R}$, and these are all archimedean.

Comment: ${\bf C}_p$ is the metric completion of the algebraic closure of the field of $p$-adic numbers ${\bf Q}_p$. Abstractly isomorphic means isomorphic as fields but not necessarily as *topological* fields. A field is a field is a field, it does not matter if you represent the elements as matrices or whatever, so it would seem one could just as easily translate the idea into the language of field extensions. And it is in that context we learn we cannot go beyond $\bf R$ without losing orderability; we must stay between $\bf Q$ and $\bf R$ for such a thing.

Comment: @anon But the situation is not so bleak as you say; an example of a non-archimedean ordered field is the surreal numbers. But they are way too big for this purpose; they form a proper class, and I am looking for smaller examples. If there is a more reasonably-sized non-archimedean ordered field, the transition to matrix representations will probably be the easy part. (As for ${\Bbb C}_p$, that doesn't sound like an ordered field, if it is algebraically closed.)

Comment: There are of course no finite ordered fields, because an ordered field has to be characteristic zero.  I don't think there are any countable non-archimedean fields, but that's getting way outside my area of expertise.  The simplest example I know of is $\mathbb{R}(x)$ with the non-Archimedean metric.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Extending your example, isn't ${\Bbb Q}(x)$ with the same metric a countable non-archimedean ordered field?

Comment: Looking a bit deeper, there's a theorem that characterizes orderable fields as those for which zero is not a sum of squares.  I'd assume that, heuristically, such orderings are non-Archimedean except when there's an obvious reason for them to be Archimedean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to go to matrix fields to find non-archimedean ordered fields, even if we restrict to the standard $+$ and $\cdot$ operation on ${\Bbb R}$. One simple example of a non-archimedean ordered field is the field of rational functions ${\Bbb R}(x)$ or ${\Bbb Q}(x)$, where $f\prec g$ if the leading coefficient of the numerator of $g-f$ is positive (i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x(g(x)-f(x))=\infty$, although the functions are usually treated only formally and not as functions).

We can reduce this to a subset of ${\Bbb R}$ by looking at ${\Bbb Q}(\pi)$ with the inherited order (which is to say, $f(\pi)\prec g(\pi)$ iff $f\prec g$). To prove that this map is injective (so that $\prec$ is well-defined on ${\Bbb Q}(\pi)$), we need only note that if $f(\pi)=g(\pi)$, then the numerator of $g-f$ has a root at $\pi$, so since $\pi$ is transcendental and the numerator of $g-f$ is a rational polynomial, it must be that $g-f=0$, i.e. $f=g$.

Thus, $({\Bbb Q}(\pi),+,\cdot,\prec)$ is isomorphic to $({\Bbb Q}(x),+,\cdot,\prec)$, so ${\Bbb Q}(\pi)\subseteq{\Bbb R}\subseteq{\Bbb C}^{1\times1}$ is a non-archimedean ordered field since ${\Bbb Q}(x)$ is.

Comment: @Chilote I probably shouldn't have called this the inherited order, but rather an image order. As I mention right afterward, this is the order such that $f(\pi)\prec g(\pi)$ iff $f\prec g$ where $f,g$ are ordered using the non-Archimedean order on $\Bbb Q(x)$. In particular, it is *not* the case that $\prec$ agrees with the standard order $<$. In this order, $n\prec\pi$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\Bbb N$ is not cofinal in $(\Bbb Q(\pi),\prec)$.